# Is it okay to use "pre-" in a clause referring to "prelaunch"?

Tags: prefixes

My question has to do with the word "prelaunch." According to the Merriam-Webster dictionary, the preferred spelling is without a hyphen. In the following clause, is it correct to use the hyphen after "pre"?

> … through the pre- and postlaunch process …

Answer (score 2):

Although the preferred spelling is without a hyphen, the hyphenated version is listed as [a variant in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prelaunch?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld). And in this construction, it definitely looks better with the hyphen. So I would write:

> … through the pre- and post-launch process …

Answer (score 0):

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149454?redirectedFrom=prelaunch#eid51451447) lists the adjective as **pre-launch.**
[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prelaunch) lists same as **prelaunch.**

And you have already posted MW's spelling.

My sense is to use either, but if you hyphenate one (**pre-launch**) hyphenate the other too (**post-launch**). Same for using no hyphens.

Even **prelaunch** can be found hyphenated and UN-hyphenated!

And **pre** is a preposition: [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149453?rskey=ftOeys&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> previous or prior to

Post can be a preposition in sense too.

Thus, the following would be correct:

… through the pre and post-launch process … (your example - without the hyphen)
… through the pre-launch and post-launch process …
… through the prelaunch and postlaunch process …

or:

> … through the (pre, pre-launch, prelaunch) and post-launch (postlaunch) process …

And finally in a sentence:

> During the launch process, both pre and post, the aberrations in X
>   were observed.

Comment: Are you suggesting that "...the pre and postlaunch process..." is OK? That looks wrong to me.

Comment: @TonyK yes, it is correct grammar